# How to addEventListener to button and everything that can be putted in button?

Tags: javascript, events, dom

Got a problem with JS events.

```
<button class="TabsItem active">
  <img src="images/type-icons/120.PNG" alt="">
</button>
```

And use `addEventListener` to `.TabItem` but when I clicked on `<img />` happens nothing. Can't figure out how to fix it so that everything that can be appeared in button will react on events.

Didn't find the answer by searching and googling.
Thanks.

UPD:
Here is js part, that rely on arrays of objects:

```
let buffer = document.querySelectorAll('.Tabs'),
        Tabs = [];

buffer.forEach(el => {
    Tabs.push({
        List: el,
        Switches: el.querySelectorAll('.TabsItem'),
        Contents: el.querySelectorAll('.TabsContentItem'),
    })
});
buffer = [];

Tabs.forEach(currentTab => {
        currentTab.Switches.forEach(tabSwitch => {
            tabSwitch.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                e.stopPropagation();
                const currentButton = e.target;
                if ((currentButton == tabSwitch) && (!currentButton.classList.contains('active'))) {
                    currentTab.Switches.forEach(currentTabSwitchClear => { currentTabSwitchClear.classList.remove('active'); });
                    currentTab.Contents.forEach(currentTabContentClear => { currentTabContentClear.classList.remove('active'); });
                    currentButton.classList.add('active');
                    currentTab.Contents[Array.from(currentTab.Switches).indexOf(currentButton)].classList.add('active');
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Is your button dynamically-generated? If so, you'll need event delegation. Also, can you please share the existing JavaScript code you have in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? :)

Comment: Post your js code please

Comment: Currently everything is static.

Comment: Can you update your question and include the relevant javascript please. When targeting a `class` it can return a list of elements (NodeList object) so depending on your selector you could use a few methods to add an event listener.

Comment: Well, js is kinda messy :) Just because it rely on array of custom Tab objects, which have arrays of TabSwitches and TabContents :)

Comment: @almazmusic only include the relevant parts. I'm sure all other functions will not be necessary, also open your browser console and check for errors. The browser console is your best friend while working/debugging javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not set currentButton = e.target, because e.target will be equal to the Image element not the button. currentButton will be equal to tabSwitch.

Try this.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.addEventListener("click", function(event){
   alert(event.target);
});
```

```html
<button id="button">
   <img src="http://www.iconarchive.com/download/i38829/google/chrome/Google-Chrome-Chromium.ico" />
</button>
```

```js
let buffer = document.querySelectorAll('.Tabs'),
        Tabs = [];

buffer.forEach(el => {
    Tabs.push({
        List: el,
        Switches: el.querySelectorAll('.TabsItem'),
        Contents: el.querySelectorAll('.TabsContentItem'),
    })
});
buffer = [];

Tabs.forEach(currentTab => {
        currentTab.Switches.forEach(tabSwitch => {
            tabSwitch.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                e.stopPropagation();
                if (!tabSwitch.classList.contains('active')) {
                    currentTab.Switches.forEach(currentTabSwitchClear => { currentTabSwitchClear.classList.remove('active'); });
                    currentTab.Contents.forEach(currentTabContentClear => { currentTabContentClear.classList.remove('active'); });
                    tabSwitch.classList.add('active');
                    currentTab.Contents[Array.from(currentTab.Switches).indexOf(tabSwitch)].classList.add('active');
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

```css
.TabsContentItem {
  display: none;
}

.TabsContentItem.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="Tabs">
<button class="TabsItem active">
  <img src="https://static.licdn.com/sc/h/9wcfzhuisnwhyauwp7t9xixy7" />
 </button>
 <button class="TabsItem">
  <img src="https://www.askwoody.com/wp-content/themes/gear_askwoody/images/ico/home-icon.png" />
 </button>
 <div class="TabsContentItem active">
   Linkedin Tab
 </div>
  <div class="TabsContentItem">
   Home Tabs
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: @almazmusic open your browser console and check for errors. If you have an error in other javascript before this function then you will find it will not run.

Comment: Well, the thing is in my if statement after the event fired. But can't understand how to complement that statement.

Comment: `const currentButton = tabSwitch;
if ((currentButton == tabSwitch))`

this will be true forever

Comment: No, I just want to make a minimal change so that you see the problem. event.target is not the button, it's the image element. You can remove that check. But it works fine.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that e.target is not a button. I think I've got a solution.

Comment: Updated the answer for removing the check.

Comment: @almazmusic what other solution you got, because the snippet works. Can you give detail?

Comment: It works, thanks a lot, but I still didn't understand why your code is work. I was thinking `addEventListener` will need to work with `(e)` and `(e.target)` but not with `tabSwitch`.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a very easy way to solve this problem with CSS.

If you make sure nothing within the button has pointer-events, clicks inside the button will always be for the button itself:

```
button * {pointer-events: none;}
```

From:
https://css-tricks.com/slightly-careful-sub-elements-clickable-things/